# How do I set up adb over usb with MyTouch 4g

Tags: android, adb

I want to set up adb to work over usb with my MyTouch 4g.  unfortunately, I am a total newb as far as android dev goes, so I really don't know what to ask. I have installed the sdk and the google usb driver but `adb devices` returns no devices.  usb debugging is turned on on my phone.  My ultimate goal is to downgrade from Gingerbread back to Froyo so I can root.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked in your device manager to make sure the ADB Interface is installed for your device?

Comment: @jack can you explain what that means or how to do it?

Comment: This is for Windows, find your "My Computer" Icon, right click, click "Manage", when the window opens, select Device Manager on the left. Now somewhere in the list on the right you should see your Android device / ADB driver.

Comment: The Google USB drivers doesn't always work - get the HTC Sync which has USB drivers as well and install the full package. This should hopefully fix your problem - of course this is only for Windows.
If you want to root your phone it's probably easier to follow one of many guides to root your device. See this for instance: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=922527 - remember rooting can brick your device.

Comment: @Darwind there is currently no root for the MyTouch running Gingerbread.  the only way to root it is to downgrade back to Froyo.  This is what I need adb for.  Once I have downgraded, I will root using the gfree method.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware that it wasn't possible to root when on Gingerbread - I just read the xda thread, but didn't notice what OS version they were talking about ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by Darwind in the comments:

> The Google USB drivers doesn't always work - get the HTC Sync which has USB drivers as well and install the full package. This should hopefully fix your problem - of course this is only for Windows

Comment: Glad I could help - I've had the same frustrations on trying to connect my phones on Windows ;)
I don't know how the drivers work on other OS's, but I've never had any issues with connecting my HTC phones on Linux or OsX.